# how to disable check box dynamically in java

Tags: java, html

i am constructing html table dynamically using java, and i want to check the checkbox automatically based on some condition, but whater the the case is the check box comes checked,

below is the code i use :

```
 if(isactive.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                         checked="checked";
                     }
                     else{
                         checked="false";
                     }
```

and the check box code :

```
htmlTable.append("<td align=\"left\" ><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"headername_"+loopvariable+"\" id=\"headername_"+loopvariable+"\" value="+id+" checked="+checked+">"+columnname.toUpperCase()+"<br></td>");

if the value is not `Y` than uncheck the checkbox is my requirement but it is not working.
```

please advise how to go about.

Regards

Comment: Note that **JavaScript!=Java**

Comment: Did you inspect your html in the browser and ensure you condition is met ?

Comment: if the isactive!='Y' than the check box looks like `<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" checked="false" value="2" id="headername_3" name="headername_3">SEX<br></td>`

Comment: if the isactive=='Y' than `<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" id="headername_1" name="headername_1">CONTACTNUMBER<br></td>`

Comment: but for the both the case the checbox comes checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `checked` property will yield a checked checkbox, regardless of what you set it to.

You need to have the entire property in your variable:

```
if(isactive.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
} else {
    checked = "";
}
```

And update your string concatenation accordingly:

```
"... value="+id+" " + checked + ">"
```